# How to Close Bootstrap Alert via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to hide a bootstrap alert via JavaScript. I have not been able to accomplish this yet... Here is my code I have :

```
 <div class="bs-example text-center " id="myAlert" runat="server" visible="false">
    <div class="alert alert-warning">
      <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>My message here
    </div>
 </div>

<asp:Button ID="btnClose" data-dismiss="modal" runat="server" Text="Close" class="btn btn-danger" OnClientClick="Clear();"/>

function Clear() {           
     $(this).closest('#myAlert').hide();
}
```

Comment: `$('#myAlert').modal('hide')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$('#myAlert').modal('toggle');
```